# How to check selected elements for value with multiple name selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to alert only if the value of all the selected elements equals "No".

I've tried to use `.val`, but not sure (if, or..) how to use `.click` to get the alert only when both radio buttons gets the value `"n"`:

```js
        $('input[name="q1"], input[name="q2"]').change(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 'y') {
            alert('Yes if any');
          }
          else {
          // both radio buttons with "No" value: (how to)
          /*
            if ($(this).click().val == 'n'){
              alert('No if both');
            }
          */
            alert('No if both');
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
       <p>Q1</p>
       <input type="radio" name="q1" value="y">Yes
       <input type="radio" name="q1" value="n">No
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
       <p>Q2</p>
       <input type="radio" name="q2" value="y">Yes
       <input type="radio" name="q2" value="n">No
    </div>
```

I want to show the second alert only when both radio buttons has the value of `"n"` but, I can't figure out how to get Jquery to check for the multiple values simultaneously/together in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `&&` operator on inputs when they are checked. Use the `:checked` selector for checking their checked status.
The condition you are looking for is this

```
if($('input[name="q1"]:checked').val() =='n' && $('input[name="q2"]:checked').val()=='n')
            alert('No if both');
          }
```

```js
$('input[name="q1"], input[name="q2"]').change(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 'y') {
            alert('Yes if any');
          }
          else {
      
         if($('input[name="q1"]:checked').val() =='n' && $('input[name="q2"]:checked').val()=='n')
            alert('No if both');
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
       <p>Q1</p>
       <input type="radio" name="q1" value="y">Yes
       <input type="radio" name="q1" value="n">No
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
       <p>Q2</p>
       <input type="radio" name="q2" value="y">Yes
       <input type="radio" name="q2" value="n">No
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get an array of selected radio buttons' values, then you can use array methods, like `includes` and `every`:

```js
const $inputs = $('input[name="q1"], input[name="q2"]');
$inputs.change(function() {
  const vals = $inputs
    .filter(':checked')
    .map((_, input) => input.value)
    .get();
  if (vals.includes('y')) {
    console.log('At least one "Yes"');
  } else if (vals.length === 2 && vals.every(val => val === 'n')) {
    console.log('Both "No"');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <p>Q1</p>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="y">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="n">No
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <p>Q2</p>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="y">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="n">No
</div>
```

By using arrays, this is easily extensible to larger numbers of radio button groups without additional code.